# ColorF: what header or library defines ColorF?

Tags: c++, panda3d

I'm trying to build the Solar-System (C++) Panda3D example for version 1.8. The problem I'm having is that when I compile it I get an error:

```
clr; g++ -c ./solar_system/tut_solar_system.cpp -o ss.o -fPIC -L/usr/lib/panda3d -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/panda3d
./solar_system/../p3util/cOnscreenText.h:75:22: error: ‘Colorf’ does not name a type
```

I have tried editing that file and including glew, glext, and glut (provided by my distro), as well as the "panda_glext" provided by Panda3D - none of those provides ColorF. (I am using archlinux and I have glew, glext, and freeglut.)

I don't know where to start looking. Google has failed me! Does anyone know where ColorF is defined?

Comment: Is it `ColorF` or `Colorf`? It could also be that it is a value and used in a place where the compiler expects a type. It would be easier to tell if you could show some lines of code around where the error occurs.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for a guide to markup.

Comment: I was wrong: it's Colorf.  
`void set_fg(const Colorf& fg);  
void set_bg(const Colorf& bg);  
void set_shadow(const Colorf& shadow);  
void set_shadow_offset(const LVecBase2f& offset);  
void set_frame(const Colorf& frame);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called LColorf, and it is a typedef for LVecBase4f, which is the generic Panda3D class for four-component floating-point values (such as vectors and colours).  The 'f' stands for 'float'; there is also an LColord typedef available.

This was a change in Panda3D 1.8.0.  Before 1.8.0, it was called Colorf (without the leading L).  Presumably, the sample programs you downloaded were designed for an earlier version.  You may change the relevant sample program to use LColorf, or you may choose to add the following before including these headers:

```
#if PANDA_NUMERIC_VERSION >= 1008000
#define Colorf LColorf
#endif
```

(Alternatively, you could use a typedef if that is what you prefer.)

For the record, the appropriate header file to include to make the LColorf symbol available is `luse.h`.  You should not include `panda_glext.h`, it is only used by the OpenGL renderer.

Comment: Thankyou so much! I was so confused because I had run into LVecBase4f while researching the documentation, but I did not realize I was straddling versions with my project. It built!